# How to get the part of a string that doesn't match another in PHP?

Tags: php, string, comparison

I've been using `similar_text` to compare two different strings, however instead of knowing how similar they are, I'd rather figure out exactly *which* part of the string doesn't match the other.

For example:

```
$str1 = "The cat was happy";
$str2 = "The cat is happy";

custom_function($str1, $str2);
```

The function should return "is", since that is the only part of `$str2` that doesn't match `$str1`.

Does anyone know of a way in PHP to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the strings into words and compare resulting arrays in next way:

```
function custom_function(string $str1, string $str2) : array {

    $arr1 = explode(' ', $str1);
    $arr2 = explode(' ', $str2);
    
    return array_combine(array_diff($arr1, $arr2), array_diff($arr2, $arr1));
}
```

[php code online](https://phpize.online/s/0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```php
function custom_function(string $str1, string $str2):string{
    $o="";
    $i=0;
    while($str1[$i]===$str2[$i]) $i++;
    $j=strlen($str1)-1;
    $k=strlen($str2)-1;
    while($str1[$j]===$str2[$k]&&$j-->=0&&$k-->=0);
    unset($j);
    while($i<=$k) $o.=$str2[$i++];
    return $o;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but I've tried it and it's not working correctly

Comment: This code cuts off the starting part of the `$str2` which is the same as the starting part of `$str1` of the same length and the ending part of the `$str2` which is the same as the ending part of `$str1` of the same length. It doesn't separate based on `' '`s, so it doesn''t work in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly did you mean, so this is another potential solution:

```php
function custom_function(string $str1,string $str2):string{
    $o="";
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l1=strlen($str1);
    $l2=strlen($str2);
    while($i<$l1&&$j<$l2){
        if($str1[$i]===$str2[$j]){
            $i++;
            $j++;
        }else{
            $o.=$str2[$j];
            while($str1[$i]!==$str2[$j]&&$i<$l1) $i++;
        }
    }
    return $o;
}
```